# Retrieving polygon geometry based on within marker geometries

Tags: postgis

I have a table for `polygon_geoms` and `marker_geoms`.

How do I retrieve polygons that have markers within them.

I have tried:

```
SELECT A.geom
FROM polygon_geoms A
LEFT JOIN marker_geoms B
ON ST_Within(B.geom, A.geom);
```

But all I get is an empty result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a sample geometry set like this:

[image]

Your query with slight modifications returns proper result (polygon id's A, D):

```
select p1.id
from (values (st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9796 48.4359)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9821 48.4354)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9837 48.4337)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9902 48.4353)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9956 48.4352)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9888 48.4288)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9907 48.4202)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9952 48.4213)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9994 48.4212)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (34.9980 48.4191)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (35.0002 48.4178)')),
(st_geomfromtext('Point (35.0021 48.4260)'))) m1(geom)
join (values ('A', st_geomfromtext('Polygon ((34.9772 48.4351, 34.9798 48.4320, 34.9847 48.4329, 34.9850 48.4356, 34.9825 48.4374, 34.9803 48.4382, 34.9783 48.4368, 34.9772 48.4351))')),
('B', st_geomfromtext('Polygon ((34.9949 48.4305, 34.9954 48.4273, 34.9985 48.4260, 35.0033 48.4281, 35.0035 48.4309, 35.0013 48.4333, 34.9968 48.4335, 34.9949 48.4305))')),
('C', st_geomfromtext('Polygon ((34.9847 48.4249, 34.9832 48.4209, 34.9862 48.4192, 34.9887 48.4201, 34.9893 48.4218, 34.9896 48.4236, 34.9887 48.4257, 34.9847 48.4249))')),
('D', st_geomfromtext('Polygon ((34.9960 48.4199, 34.9972 48.4165, 35.0008 48.4168, 35.0022 48.4210, 34.9984 48.4231, 34.9960 48.4199))'))) p1(id, geom)
on st_within(m1.geom, p1.geom)
group by p1.id
```

So, I'm guessing, it's either something is wrong with your geometries or they do not overlap in deed.

Comment: Thanks. I got an idea why it does not return my expected result. I think they don't have same srid.

Comment: ...most probably